# Removing a unique pointer from an array of unique pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, unique-ptr

I'm trying to create a class which maintains a fixed size vector of unique pointers to managed objects, like so:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Myclass>> myVector;
```

The vector gets initialized like so:

```
myVector.resize(MAX_OBJECTS,nullptr);
```

Now, what I need to to, is to be able to, on request, remove one of the stored unique pointers without affecting the size of the vector.

I also need to safely add elements to the vector too, without using push_back or emplace_back.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I want the vector to be of constant size because I want to be able to add and remove elements in constant time.

Comment: Well where should an element be added? The first `nullptr` space? Or to a specific index?

Comment: You probably want to use `std::array<>` if you need a fixed sized array.

Comment: Why is it important that the size of the vector not change?

Comment: Does order of pointers in array matter?  How do you intend to detect if a pointer is still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a vector of fixed size, use `std::array`.

To remove a unique_ptr in an index, you can use `std::unique_ptr::reset()`:

```
myVector[i].reset()
```

To add an element to a specific index (overwriting what was there before) you can use `std::unique_ptr::reset()` with the new pointer as parameter:

```
myVector[i].reset(new Myptr(myparameter));
```

Reading a reference may also help:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: `std::unique_ptr.release()` won't call the object's destructor. I think you meant `std::unique_ptr.reset()` (no parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use a `std::array<>` rather than forcing `std::vector<>` to behave like one.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out you should use `std::array` if the size is fixed.
E.g like this:

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<YourType>, MAX_OBJECTS> myVector;
```

You can then remove or add a new pointer like this.

```
for(auto& v : myVector)
    if(v && predicate)
        v.reset();// or v.reset(ptr) to set a new one
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use STL algorithm std::remove, like this:

```
// all items that should be removed will be the range between removeAt and end(myVector)
auto removeAt = std::remove_if(begin(myVector), end(myVector), 
                               ShouldRemovePredicate);

// reset all items that should be removed to be nullptr
for(auto it = removeAt; it != end(myVector); ++it)
    it->reset();
```

In addition, if the size is known at compile-time I would suggest using `std::array<unique_ptr<MyObject>, SIZE>` instead of a vector. However, if SIZE is not known at compile-time your code is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::array` instead of a `std::vector` since you know the number of the elements beforehand and you could add and remove elements like the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

class foo {
  std::size_t id;
  public:
  foo() : id(0) {}
  foo(std::size_t const _id) : id(_id) {}
  std::size_t getid() const { return id; }
};

auto main() ->int {
  // construct an array of 3 positions with `nullptr`s
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<foo>, 3> arr;

  // fill positions
  std::unique_ptr<foo> p1(new foo(1));
  arr[0] = std::move(p1);
  std::unique_ptr<foo> p2(new foo(2));
  arr[1] = std::move(p2);
  std::unique_ptr<foo> p3(new foo(3));
  arr[2] = std::move(p3);

  // print array
  for(auto &i : arr) if(i != nullptr) std::cout << i->getid() << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // reset first position (i.e., remove element at position 0)
  arr[0].reset();

  // print array
  for(auto &i : arr) if(i != nullptr) std::cout << i->getid() << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5553dd4d97fe73c1)